# The limit form representation of gamma function

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

I was reading about Gamma function, its properties, its applications, etc., and I found the following property:

$$\Gamma(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^x}{(x)_{n+1}}.$$

I want to prove this property, so I used the definition of the Gamma function:
$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty{t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt}$; and the definition of $e^{-t}$: $e^{-t}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{t}{n})^n\, dt$. Substitute in $\Gamma(x)$, and simplify:

$$\Gamma(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^nt^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^ndt.$$

Now, I am stuck here, and asking if there any way to continue in that way or not.

Comment: FYI: $(x)_{n+1}$ is shifted factorial

Comment: It is equivalent to (x+n)(x+n-1)(x+n-2)(x+n-3)...(x+2)(x+1)x

Comment: The limit of $\int_0^n$ by itself is $\int_0^\infty$ (by definition), and the limit of $(1-\frac tn)^n$ by itself is $e^{-t}$. Do you know these two facts? Or are you worried about why one can take those limits simultaneously?

Comment: I didn't understand well what you mean, but I know that $\int_0^\infty$ is equivalent to the limit of $\int_0^n$ when n goes to $\infty$. Also, I know that the limit $(1-\frac{t}{n})^n$ when n goes to $\infty$ is the same as $e^{-t}$

Comment: @GregMartin Actually this is my question, I am asking about the next steps if possible because I am stuck.

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing a proof of what I suspect was this same proposition, that goes like this: You have $$\begin{align} & \bullet\quad \Gamma(1)=1\text{ and} \\ {} \\ & \bullet\quad \text{for all } x>0,\quad \Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x) \text{ and} \\ {} \\ & \bullet\quad \Gamma \text{ is log-convex, i.e. } \log\Gamma \text{ is convex.} \end{align} $$ Then somehow prove that if a function has those properties, it must be equal to that proposed limit. A corollary is that this is the only function from $(0,+\infty)$ into $\mathbb R$ that has those three properties. $\qquad$

Comment: (But I am less than $100\%$ sure that the limit expression you wrote down is the same as what I saw years ago.) $\qquad$

Comment: $\text{“$f$ is convex”}$ is defined as meaning that every chord of the graph of $f,$ i.e. every line segment whose two endpoints are on the graph, lies entirely (weakly) above the graph. A theorem says that if $f''>0$ everywhere, then $f$ is convex. $\qquad$

Comment: Since the integrand is increasing as $n$ increases, the Monotone Convergence Theorem should allow you to conclude that the limit is what you want it to be.

Comment: @GregMartin, I just want to prove it rigorously without induction.

Comment: I know that the proof is not that easy, and I am also trying to figure it out.

Comment: Perform the change of integration variables $s=nt$ and then use the [beta integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E1).

Answer (score 2):

As @Gary commented, you could use the beta function. Another solution using the gaussian hypergeometric function is
$$I_n=\int t^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\,dt=\frac{t^x }{x}\, _2F_1\left(-n,x;x+1;\frac{t}{n}\right)$$
$$J_n=\int_0^n t^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\,dt=\frac{n^x }{x}\, _2F_1\left(-n,x;x+1;1\right)=\frac{n^x }{x}\,\frac{\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (x+1)}{\Gamma (n+x+1)}$$ Rewrite
$$J_n=\frac{\Gamma (x+1)}x \Bigg[n^x \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+x+1) }\Bigg]=\Gamma (x)\Bigg[n^x \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+x+1) }\Bigg]$$ Now, using series for large values of $n$
$$\log\Bigg[n^x \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+x+1) }\Bigg]=-\frac{x (x+1)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$J_n=\Gamma (x)\Bigg[1-\frac{x (x+1)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\Bigg]$$